# How can I pass a dynamic database name to a decorator?

Tags: python, django, orm, decorator

Django has a decorator function called `@transaction.commit_manually`. I am attempting to pass a parameter to this decorator, `(using=db)`. `db` varies depending on which database is being used, based on business rules.  What is the best way to pass the current database to this decorator?  I tried to use an inner function, thus:

```
def func(db):
    stuff = _business logic_

    @transaction.commit_manually(using=db)
    def do_transaction(stuff):
        try:
            stuff.save(using=db)
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
        else:
            transaction.commit()

    do_transaction()
```

However, this fails. The error I discovered with `pdb` is that the inner block is "Not under transaction management."  How do I overcome this problem?

Traceback from `pdb`:

```
-> success = transactional_registration()
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py(338)_commit_manually()
-> return func(*args, **kw)
> /home/syrion/dev/registration.py(59)transactional_registration()
-> transaction.rollback()
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py(210)rollback()
-> set_clean(using=using)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py(125)set_clean()
-> raise TransactionManagementError("This code isn't under transaction management"
```

**Edit**: I fixed my own problem. The internal function solution works correctly, but I needed to be calling `rollback()` and `commit()` with a using parameter, i.e. `transaction.commit(using=db)`, as well. I find that unintuitive, but...

Comment: can you add a raise after transaction.rollback() and post the stacktrace + full error ?

Comment: Why are you making this so complex?  Why isn't `func` a callable object?

Comment: `func` is a callable method on an object.  If I decorate `func` itself, the database is out of scope.

Comment: I'll also note that, if I try to set the db in the constructor of the enclosing object, and reference `self.db`, I get an error indicating that `self` is out of scope on the decorator.

Comment: You don't need a decorator at all if you use a simple callable object.  Why aren't you creating a simple callable and avoiding the confusing decorator entirely?

Comment: I am trying to use transactions in Django.  The clearest way to do this seems to be a transaction decorator.  Is there a better way to do it with a callable object?

Comment: "Is there a better way to do it with a callable object".  I still don't see why you have `def do_transaction(stuff):` at all.   Why is there an inner function definition?  Why is this so complex?  Please explain why you think an inner function definition is helpful.

Comment: If I try to use the decorator on the outer function, `db` is not in scope.  I attempted to overcome this by passing in `db` to the outer function, defining `do_transaction()` within the body of the outer function and decorating it within the context of the outer function. This way, I don't receive an out of scope error -- but it also behaves as though the inner function is not within transaction management.

Comment: Note that you can now use context managers with Django transaction decorators; that might allow you to dump the inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this quite often in my code since I put a lot of stress on the ORM. Since I'm not a big fan of decorator syntax I use the `with` statement.

```
def do_transaction(stuff, db):
    with transaction.commit_manually(using=db)
        try:
            stuff.save(using=db)
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
        else:
            transaction.commit(using=db)
```

This should work. Not sure if you're going to need `(using=db)` in your `transaction.rollback()`, though. I'm sure you can do the research on that. But you do need `(using=db)` in `transaction.commit(using=db)`.